# Take photo if app is not active

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is it possible for an App on an iPhone/iPad to take a photo even if the app is not in foreground? Or maybe even automatically when the user unlocks the phone?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Apple would consider this a security + privacy problem.

Comment: Thats what i thought

Answer (score -2):

No your app must be in foreground and you have to use `UIImagePickerController`
It is well explained [here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/)

Comment: You are incorrect in assuming UIImagePickerController is your only option, in fact, the link that you've posted shows how to achieve the same using AVCaptureSession.